# Linear optimization and the dual

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

Write the dual of:

$$\min c^Tx\quad \text{s.t.}\quad Ax=b,\quad l\le x\le f$$

where $l$ and $f$ are fixed lower and upper bounds on the variables $x$.

Simplify the dual so that it has the fewest possible number of variables and constraints.

I find in standard form that $x\ge l$, $-x \ge -f$

So far for the dual I have

$$\max b^Tu,\quad\text{s.t.}\quad A^Tu \le c$$

$u$ is free because the $x$ is an equality constraint.

I think I should also consider the bounds on $x$ when writing the dual, but am not sure how to incorporate this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Through the Lagrangian

(This is the usual bazooka when you're not sure what to do)

So if you write the Lagrangian, you get:

$$ L(x,\lambda,\nu,\omega) = c^T x + \lambda^T(Ax-b) + \nu^T(l-x) + \omega^T(x-f) $$

which you can rearrange as

$$ L(x,\lambda,\nu,\omega) = -\lambda^T b +\nu^T l - \omega^T f + (A^T\lambda - \nu + \omega + c)^Tx $$

The dual is the function given by the infimum of the Lagrangian in $x$:

$$g(\lambda,\nu,\omega) = (-\lambda^T b +\nu^T l - \omega^T f) + \inf_x  \,\,(A^T\lambda - \nu + \omega + c)^Tx$$

which is $-\infty$ unless $(A^T\lambda - \nu + \omega + c)=0$. That's one of your dual constraint.

Now you should maximize the dual with that constraint. The constraints over $\lambda, \nu, \omega$ are simple: since $\lambda$ corresponds to an equality constraint, it is unconstrained, $\omega,\nu$ have to be non-negative. In other words:

$$ \max_{\lambda,\nu,\omega}\,\, (-b^T\lambda +l^T\nu - f^T\omega) $$

such that

$$ (A^T\lambda - \nu + \omega +c) = 0, \nu\ge0, \omega\ge 0. $$

(Boyd and Vandenberghe's book is probably a good reference for this type of stuff)

#### Through the standard form

(This is the nicer technique if you remember your LP stuff)

You can put your problem in the standard inequality form by defining:

$$ M:= \left(\begin{array}{c} A\\-A\\-I\\+I\end{array}\right), \quad d:= \left(\begin{array}{c} b\\-b\\-l\\f\end{array}\right)$$

the problem then reads

$$ \min c^T x\quad \text{s.t.}\quad Mx\le d  $$

which has dual

$$ \max -d^T\lambda\quad \text{s.t.}\quad M^T\lambda + c = 0,\quad \lambda \ge 0  $$

Note that here the lambda has the size of $d$ so its not the same dimensions as in the first approach. If you correspondingly write

$$ \lambda := \left(\begin{array}{c} \lambda_1\\\lambda_2\\\lambda_3\\\lambda_4\end{array}\right) $$

then the inequality can be written

$$ (A^T(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) - \lambda_3 +\lambda_4 +c)=0 $$

whilst the objective can be written

$$ (b^T(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) +l^T\lambda_3 - f^T\lambda_4)$$

Let $\lambda_0:=\lambda_1-\lambda_2$, it is now unconstrained while $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_4$ still have to be $\ge 0$. Rewriting:

$$ \max_{\lambda_0,\lambda_3,\lambda_4} \quad (-b^T\lambda_0+l^T\lambda_3-f^T\lambda_4)  $$

such that

$$ (A^T\lambda_0 - \lambda_3 +\lambda_4 +c)=0, \quad \lambda_3,\lambda_4\ge 0$$

which is obviously identical to the previous solution identifying $\lambda\leftrightarrow \lambda_0, \nu\leftrightarrow \lambda_3, \omega\leftrightarrow \lambda_4$